# Python: Determining Oracle Database Column Data Types in SQL Select List

Tags: python-3.x, sqldatatypes, cx-oracle

How to determine column data types for columns in a select list  using Oracle and the cx_Oracle module in Python. Essentially a kind of cursor introspection.

I have seen solutions where you need to query the Oracle data dictionary based upon the the table name. However, if you need to write code which executes SQL dynamically, say SQL stored in a file, which joins two or more tables, things get tricky. This method allows you to interrogate the cursor and for any given column in the select list, irrespective of which table or view it is derived from and thereby determine the column's data type.

Comment: please read [mcve] and provide some more context to question using some example

Answer (score 5):

So here is the solution. Say I have my cursor cur defined and execute my SQL as follows:

```
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT colX, colY, colZ,... FROM my_table')
```

We can now interrogate the cursor object and if we want say, the names of the columns returned as a list, we can do:

```
    col_names = [row[0] for row in cur.description]
```

So here, col_names[1] would show as 'colY' from our example SQL.

In a similar way we can grab a data types list:

```
    col_types = [row[1] for row in cur.description]
```

So now we can test the data type by doing something something like:

```
    if (col_types[i].__name__ == 'DATETIME'):
        ...
```

or if we simply want to report the data type we can use:

```
    print (col_types[i].__name__)
```

NOTE: The data types observed approximate to Oracle data types. For example, an Oracle DATE column will be described as DATETIME and VARCHAR2 will show as STRING. To see the complete mappings, see:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-queries-101587.html